# bash ignorecase match pattern in file and color that line, print all to screen

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, logs

I want is to `cat` a log file and highlight certain lines with color based on a pattern match *but* to **ignore case**. For example:

- When the log file has the word success then make that line green.
- When it finds error make that line red etc.

This is what I have so far. It is based on cat and awk (although when I used `man awk` I got man for `gawk` instead). I am using Debian Jessie.

```
 #!/bin/bash

[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$1" ] && logfile="$1" || logfile="-"
cat $logfile | awk '
/install/ {print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"}
/success/ {print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"}
/status/ {print "\033[33m" $0 "\033[39m"}
/info/ {print "\033[33m" $0 "\033[39m"}
/error/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m"}
/fail/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m"}
'
```

I have used all manner of stuff, but I end up with all my text in 1 colour, no colour, or the case is not being ignored. Things like IGNORECASE=1 don't seem to work.

I am happy to use something else, as I just pinched this script from another question. Below is exactly what I want in case someone wants to suggest a new script.

1. use a command followed by a filename and print the contents to the terminal (using bash would be ideal)
2. in my script I would like to add strings to match and make those lines in a log/text file a certain color when printed to the screen. eg. find the word error and make that line red
3. ignore case for the words I want to match, eg. find the word error, ERROR, or any combination of upper lower case, like Error, or ERRor etc. Then print that line to the screen in a red color.

The idea is to be able to easily spot important parts in some of my backup, and things like apache access logs or whatever. I intend to find the important key words I am after and then simply adding those in my script.

Below is a snippet of the beginning and end of one of log files as an example:

```
INFO: tar attempt number 0
/home/user/domains/
/home/user/domains/website.com/
/home/user/domains/website.com/logs/
/home/user/domains/website.com/logs/Apr-2015.tar.gz.4
/home/user/domains/website.com/logs/Apr-2015.tar.gz
/home/user/domains/website.com/logs/Apr-2015.tar.gz.1
/home/user/domains/website.com/logs/Apr-2015.tar.gz.3
/home/user/domains/website.com/logs/Apr-2015.tar.gz.2
/home/user/domains/website.com/public_html/
/home/user/domains/website.com/public_html/api.php
/home/user/domains/website.com/public_html/index.html
/home/user/domains/website.com/public_html/favicon.ico
/home/user/domains/website.com/public_html/favicon1.ico
SUCCESS: website tar exists.
INFO: DB backup dump, attempt number 0
SUCCESS: DB backup file created.
/home/user/dakka_backups/user_db-Thu.2015-04-30.sql
INFO: CN Website and DB backed up on Thu.2015-04-30.
```

Comment: Can you share a  snippet of your logfile also ?

Comment: I've added an example to the end of my question. I was intending to check out a few logs like apache access logs, ssh logs etc and define a few key words I want to have coloured. So ultimately I wanted to use this against all kinds of log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk has a function called 'tolower':

```
cat $logfile | awk '
     tolower($0) ~ /install/ {print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"; next;}
     tolower($0) ~ /success/ {print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"; next;}
     tolower($0) ~ /status/ {print "\033[33m" $0 "\033[39m";  next;}
     tolower($0) ~ /info/ {print "\033[33m" $0 "\033[39m";    next;}
     tolower($0) ~ /error/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m";   next;}
     tolower($0) ~ /fail/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m";    next;}
     { print; }
'
```

With Bash, you can use `shopt -s nocasematch` for case insensitive pattern matching. eg.

```
mystring="AbCdEfG"
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ ${mystring} == abcdefg ]] ; then
     echo "is a match!!"
fi
```

Comment: Almost! That displays only what I am matching, is there a way to match everything else without changing the colours? I want the log to print out normally like when you use `cat filename` except what my script matches should be in different colours...hope that made sense?

Comment: @dakka - I've updated the answer.